# CQWP queries too many items

Tags: content-query-web-part, performance

I have a CQWP that queries an entire Site Collection. The Site Collection contains around 10,000+ documents. I use the CQWP to try to get the 25 most recent documents from this 10,000.

Problem is, it fails. It shows me this error:

> Your query returned a greater number of results than the web
>   application's query throttling limit. Please adjust the configuration
>   of this Web Part o increase the throttling Limit.

Has anyone worked around this? Did you develop your own custom webpart instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one way you can work around this is to use the [lightning conductor](http://lightningtools.com/products/lightning-conductor-web-part-2010/) webpart.

it runs on an elevated account which will not look at the threshold.

needless to say, this needs to be used with caution, but the built in cache features helps reduce performance impact

another approach is to use [content iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798376.aspx)

> SharePoint Server provides a new API, ContentIterator, to help with
>   accessing more than 5,000 items in a large list without hitting a list
>   throttling limit and receiving an SPQueryThrottleException.
>   ContentIterator implements a callback pattern for segmenting the query
>   for processing a single item at a time. Consider using this capability
>   if you need to process a large number of items that may exceed a
>   throttling limit.

Comment: Thanks Tiago! Content Iterator looks promising. Will have a go with that.